# How to compile-time construct a literal string by concatenating N instances of a literal string S end-to-end?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm developing a cuda program. There is a large integer type `LargeInteger<typename E, uint32_t N>`, which represents a large integer constructed from `N` instances of type `E`. For example, `LargeInteger<uint32_t, 12>` represents a large integer that requires `12` `uint32_t` components to represent.

```
template<typename E, uint32_t N>
class LargeInteger{
public:
    void Print() const{
        //How can I print each value in the value_ array with just a single printf call?
    }
private:
    E value_[N];
};
```

Now, for debugging purposes, I need to provide a `Print()` function within the class to print the value of this large integer on both host side and device side. For performance and atomicity considerations, I need to be able to print all components of the large integer's value in a single printf function call.
For example, for `LargeInteger<uint32_t, 3>`, I need to be able to call `printf("%08x%08x%08x", value_[0], value_[1], value_[2])` within the `Print()` function. Whereas, for `LargeInteger<uint16_t, 2>`, I need to call `printf("%04x%04x%04x", value_[0], value_[1])` within the `Print()` function.

This problem mainly involves solving two issues:

- 1. How to generate the format string based on template parameters `E` and `N` (which needs to be done at compile-time).
- 2. How to provide the other arguments required by `printf` based on the template parameter `N`.

For issue 2, my approach is to utilize parameter pack expansion. For issue 1, I can use template specialization to determine whether to use `"%08x"` or `"%04x"` and so on as the basis for constructing the final format string. The problem ultimately evolves into how to construct, at compile-time, a literal string composed of `N` concatenated instances of a single literal string `S`, based on the template parameter `N` of a `uint32_t` type class, along with one literal string `S`.

The method I initially thought of is to use macro functions to concatenate multiple strings, as shown below:

```
#define IntegerFormatString(StringUnit, StringNum) \
    IntegerFormatString_Impl(StringUnit, StringNum)

#define IntegerFormatString_Impl(StringUnit, StringNum) \
    IntegerFormatStringRepeat_##StringNum(StringUnit)

#define IntegerFormatStringRepeat_1(StringUnit) StringUnit
#define IntegerFormatStringRepeat_2(StringUnit) StringUnit##StringUnit
#define IntegerFormatStringRepeat_3(StringUnit) StringUnit##StringUnit##StringUnit
```

However, this approach has a maximum limit on `StringNum`. Another approach is to use compile-time computations to achieve string concatenation, but it seems that functions like `sprintf` are not supported for compile-time operations.

Any idea?

Comment: which C++ standard does your compiler support? It matters a lot for `constexpr` functions.

Comment: `printf` is not magical. It will use a loop internally, and you might as well write the same loop by hand. That should be a lot easier that generating the format string, might work faster too.

Comment: I also would not make a print function but I would make a function that would return a std::string() and/or provide a freestanding std::ostream& operator<<  for your class. The last thing you should do is to try to solve your problem with macros. Use function templates

Comment: I wouldn't use a printf format string at all.   I'd write a simple loop to create a `std::string`  or do the equivalent using algorithms and streaming facilities from the standard library.

Comment: @Eugene I'm using C++14

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am developing a CUDA program, and within CUDA device functions, printf is atomic, which ensures that multiple threads printing simultaneously will not result in their output being interleaved.

Comment: In a CUDA program, if you want to print information to standard output within a device function, you can only achieve this through the CUDA-specific printf function.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>

template <typename E, std::size_t N>
class LargeInteger
{
  public:
    // A dummy constructor.
    LargeInteger()
    {
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
            value_[i] = i + 1;
    }

    void Print() const
    {
        static constexpr auto format = []{
            std::array<char, N*4+1> ret{};
            for (std::size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                char *ptr = ret.data() + i * 4;
                ptr[0] = '%';
                ptr[1] = '0';
                ptr[2] = '0' + sizeof(E) * 2;
                ptr[3] = 'x';
            }
            return ret;
        }();

        std::apply([&](const auto &... elem){
            printf(format.data(), elem...);
        }, value_);
    }
private:
    std::array<E, N> value_;
};

int main()
{
    LargeInteger<char, 3> i;
    i.Print();
}
```

Generating the format string isn't hard, those days you can do it like you would in non-constexpr code. I'm doing this in an immediately-invoked lambda and assigning the result to a `static constexpr` variable to make sure it happens at compile-time.

Passing each element to `printf` can be done with `std::apply`, if we substitute the plain array for `std::array` (which should be equivalent for most purposes).

Comment: According to C++ standard, constant expressions are not guaranteed to be evaluated at compile time

Comment: @leihu Maybe. What happens in practice is, assigning the result to a `constexpr` variable forces it to be evaluated at compile-time.

Comment: I have a question. Even though the "format" variable itself is marked with the constexpr specifier, it is not used in places where constant expressions are required afterward. Will this also force the compiler to generate "format" at compile-time?

Comment: @leihu From my experience, yes. You can check the generated assembly from different compilers on https://gcc.godbolt.org/ to confirm that.